# Rails Select from JSON Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, foursquare

I have a JSON array that was returned from Foursquare; let's call it `@venues`. I want to be able to "select" a venue via a drop down box and I want it to be part of a form.

That means I want to be able to select a specific venue by name (i.e. in this case, Hotel Utah Saloon), and save it's `id` into a model. To clarify, I will only be saving the venues I select, not all of them.

Through research, I have found myself confused between `select`, `collection_select`, and `select_tag`. Keep in mind that this is JSON directly from a `JSON.parse` method and is not a DB model.

How do I create this drop down in a form?

For clarification, `@venues` looks something like this:

```
[
            {
               "beenHere":8,
               "venue":{
                  "id":"3fd66200f964a52023f11ee3",
                  "name":"Hotel Utah Saloon",
                  "contact":{
                     "phone":"4155466300",
                     "formattedPhone":"(415) 546-6300",
                     "twitter":"hotelutah"
                  },
                  "location":{
                     "address":"500 4th St",
                     "crossStreet":"Corner of Bryant",
                     "lat":37.77947007181946,
                     "lng":-122.39816943501836,
                     "postalCode":"94107",
                     "city":"San Francisco",
                     "state":"CA",
                     "country":"United States",
                     "cc":"US"
                  },
                  "categories":[
                     {
                        "id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1e9931735",
                        "name":"Rock Club",
                        "pluralName":"Rock Clubs",
                        "shortName":"Rock Club",
                        "icon":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/img\/categories\/arts_entertainment\/musicvenue_rockclub.png",
                        "parents":[
                           "Arts & Entertainment",
                           "Music Venues"
                        ],
                        "primary":true
                     }
                  ],
                  "verified":true,
                  "stats":{
                     "checkinsCount":6654,
                     "usersCount":3330,
                     "tipCount":50
                  },
                  "likes":{
                     "count":0,
                     "groups":[

                     ]
                  },
                  "beenHere":{
                     "count":0
                  }
               }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller

```
@venues = JSON.parse @venues
```

View

```
<%= select(:model, :venue_id, @venues.map {|v| [ v['venue']['name'], v['venue']['id'] ] }) %>
```

Or to be more cleaner:

Controller

```
@venues = JSON.parse @venues
@venues_list = @venues.map { |v| v['venue'] }
```

View

```
<%= select(:model, :venue_id, @venues_list.map {|v| [ v['name'], v['id'] ] }) %>
```

More information about [select helper](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select).

Comment: What is `:model` in this case?

Comment: your model where you want to save the venue id (eg. `:venue`)