# Ruby on rails and JSON to create Select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, forms

I want to create a form like that :

```
<select> 
 <option>
</select>
```

with ruby on rails, but it is for countries (and there is a lot of countries in the world haha), so I don't want to write everyone on my view, so I want to put a JSON file with all countries, and get theme in my option items ( with each method maybe )

I don't know where I have to put my json file in my rails app and how call it in my view,

does someone could help me ?

Comment: You need `select_tag` and `options_for_select`. These are rails methods. Read their docs.

Comment: see this question for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595327/rails-select-from-json-array

Comment: Thank you Sergio, but I just want to know where I have to put my json file on my app ? (which folder) and how I have to request it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest location to put your JSON file is in the same directory as your controllers -- although doing this kind of thing repeatedly will quickly make a mess out of your controllers folder.

Once you've done that you can read it from your controller like this:

```
file = File.read('./countries.json')
countries = JSON.parse(file)
```

and then map countries to the data type that `options_for_select` expects.

Once you have that working, I'd recommend making a helper that knows how to read the json file, cache it's data, and return it.  Store the json file in the same directory as the helper.  Reference the helper in your controller.

Also note: the JSON gem is required for this.

In your helper, you want to create this method:

```
def countries_for_select
    file = File.read('./countries.json')
    countries = JSON.parse(file)
    countries.map {|c| [ c['country']['label'], v['country']['country_code'] ] })
end
```

`.map` translates the fields from your countries json object to the `[[name,key], ...]` array that `options_for_select` expects.

Per the form helper on the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), the syntax for `select_tag` looks like this

```
<%= select_tag(:country, options_for_select(...)) %>
```

but we already created the helper `countries_for_select` to match the format that the `select_tag` is expecting.  So all you need to do is this:

```
<%= select_tag(:country, countries_for_select) %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Is that obligated to put this in controller ? I can't put it in view ?

Comment: You definitely want this (at least) in your controller.  But I recommend moving the meat of the logic into a helper class.

Comment: @AntoninMrchd: __definitely__ not view.

Comment: Ok ! Thank you very much for your time ! I'm going to try this !

Comment: I create an helper.rb or I put it in the application_helper.rb ?

Comment: I have created a helper def like that :                                                          def json_reader
    require 'json'
    file = File.read('./countries.json')
    countries = JSON.parse(file)
  end

Comment: Cool -- so now create another method: def options_for_countries ... and map the json into a key:value object for the <option/> elements.  Then you call  <%= select(:model, :country_id, options_for_countries) %> in your view.

Comment: Ok, but I have a probleme, how my controller have to look like ? I'm a bit lost

Comment: And, What I have to put in the options_for_countries ? I new in rails, I learning by doing, but sometimes its rally difficult to understand everything

Comment: @AntoninMrchd There is plenty of information here and in the linked post to achieve exactly what you need to do.  Creating a global variable in a controller is simple and demonstrated in the linked post.  A helper is a better design choice.  Choose whatever option meets your needs and is easiest to comprehend.   Eventually you're going to have to learn by reading -- otherwise your code will be inefficient and insecure.

Comment: @axlj I'm really sorry for having removed the answer, it wasn't intentional .. Thank you so much for your time I'm going to try with all elements that I have here

Comment: No worries -- updated answer with more details around how options_for_select works.

Comment: @axlj thank you very much, I understand now, but I have an other question, when I try to get "create#post" action, I have this error message : No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./countries.json , I think that the browser dosen't find my json file ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128389/discussion-between-axlj-and-antonin-mrchd).